# Mangled rendering when transforming scene coordinates instead of camera coordinates

Tags: matrix, three.js, 3d, mapbox-gl-js, gltf

I've been learning how to integrate ThreeJS with Mapbox, using [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/). It struck me as weird that the approach is to leave the loaded model in its own coordinate system, and transform the camera location on render. So I attempted to rewrite the code, so that the GLTF model is transformed when loaded, then the ThreeJS camera is just synchronised with the Mapbox camera, with no further modifications.

The code now looks like this:

```js
function newScene() {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // create two three.js lights to illuminate the model
    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    const directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight2);

    return scene;
}

function newRenderer(map, gl) {
    // use the Mapbox GL JS map canvas for three.js
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: map.getCanvas(),
        context: gl,
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    return renderer;
}    

// create a custom layer for a 3D model per the CustomLayerInterface
export function addModel(modelPath, origin, altitude = 0, orientation = [Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]) {
    const coords = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(origin, altitude);

    // transformation parameters to position, rotate and scale the 3D model onto the map
    const modelTransform = {
        translateX: coords.x,
        translateY: coords.y,
        translateZ: coords.z,
        rotateX: orientation[0],
        rotateY: orientation[1],
        rotateZ: orientation[2],
        /* Since our 3D model is in real world meters, a scale transform needs to be
        * applied since the CustomLayerInterface expects units in MercatorCoordinates.
        */
        scale: coords.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits()
    };
    const scaleVector = new THREE.Vector3(modelTransform.scale, -modelTransform.scale, modelTransform.scale)

    return {
        id: "3d-model",
        type: "custom",
        renderingMode: "3d",
        onAdd: function(map, gl) {
            this.map = map;
            this.camera = new THREE.Camera();
            this.scene = newScene();
            this.renderer = newRenderer(map, gl);

            // use the three.js GLTF loader to add the 3D model to the three.js scene
            new THREE.GLTFLoader()
                .load(modelPath, gltf => {
                    gltf.scene.position.fromArray([coords.x, coords.y, coords.z]);
                    gltf.scene.setRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().fromArray(orientation));
                    gltf.scene.scale.copy(scaleVector);

                    this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
                    const bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(gltf.scene);
                    console.log(bbox);
                    this.scene.add(new THREE.Box3Helper(bbox, 'blue'));
                });
        },
        render: function(gl, matrix) {            
            this.camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);

            this.renderer.state.reset();
            this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
            // this.map.triggerRepaint();
        }
    }
}
```

It basically works, in that a model is loaded and drawn in the right location in the Mapbox world. However, instead of looking like this:

[image]

It now looks like this, a mangled mess that jitters around chaotically as the camera moves:

[image]

[image]

I'm not yet familiar enough with ThreeJS to have any idea what I did wrong.

Here's a side-by-side comparison of the old, functional code on the right, vs the new broken code on the left.

[image]

### Further investigation

I suspect possibly the cause is to do with shrinking all the coordinates down to within the [0..1] range of the projected coordinate system, and losing mathematical precision, perhaps. When I scale the model up by 100 times, it renders like this - messy and glitchy, but at least recognisable as something.

[image]

Comment: What are the coords.xyz you're translating your model to ? My hypothesis is you're having some kind of z fighting... try setting your renderer({ logarithmicDepthBuffer:true }) and see if it helps ?

Comment: Not quite sure how to answer that. The transformation is to the Mercator projection, where the surface of the earth ranges from 0 (at -180 longitude) to 1 (at 180 longitude), and 0 (about +85 degrees latitude) to 1 (about -85 degrees latitude).
I tried your suggestion, but it didn't change anything.